# S3 & node.js / Define new agent for aws.sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use `node.js` and `aws-sdk`.

I want to define a new agent from a require aws-sdk.

```
  var agent = new http.Agent()
  agent.maxSockets = 20;
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId: "acc",
  secretAccessKey: "sec", region:"us-east-1", httpOptions: {agent: agent}});
```

For some reason, it gives me an Networking error when I use `var download = s3t.getObject(s3Params);`

What can be the reason? How I define new agent?

Edit : This is the error:

```
{ [NetworkingError: read ECONNRESET]
  message: 'read ECONNRESET',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you define a new https agent in your AWS S3 client:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    httpOptions: {
        agent: new https.Agent(...)
}})
```

Or you can globally update the AWS client config:

```
AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new http.Agent(...)
  }
})
```